# How to create a branch in a bare repository in Git

Tags: git

I current have a bare repo thats acts as a central repo for my team. The bare repo currently only have a branch "master". How can I create more branches on the bare repo?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually you don't create branches directly in the bare repository, but you push branches from one work repository to the bare

```
git push origin myBranch
```

Update: Worth to mention

Like Paul Pladijs mentioned in the comments with

```
git push origin localBranchName:remoteBranchName
```

you push (and create, if not exists) your local branch to the remote with a different branch name, that your local one. And to make it complete with

```
git push origin :remoteBranchName
```

you delete a remote branch.

Comment: If you want to give the branch another name then use: `git push origin localBranchName:remoteBranchName`

Comment: What jiberjaber is this? The guy asks a simple question: "how to create a branch in a bare repo?". Of course any advices are may be welcome but keep them for the end, AFTER you answer the question. Did anyone asked you what is "usually" happens. Maybe he is the manager and don't have nor want a checked-out work tree. The correct answer is @arcyqwerty 's answer ( git branch branchname ). Mark it as accepted, please.

Comment: Hi @Yannis. No. The question is indeed "how to create a branch in a bare repo", but you _never_ create a branch in a bare repo directly. Really. Never. arcyqwerty actually tells you the very same, because the relevant part is "git push...". That, is, what 'creates' the branch in the bare repository. His 'git branch...' is local.

Comment: @KingCrunch : Yes, but you do understand that your answer is only on the "how to proper do" and not at all on the "how to do" which I believe is mandatory to be in the answer. In my case, for example, I use git over company's garbage VCS where I work a lot with worktrees and I usually manage my branches directly on the bare repo (so not exactly never as you say). I was looking for this answer (and actually was at that time pretty frustrated at work, hence the aggressive in the comment) and only arcyqwerty's response gave it to me.

real answer > advices

Answer (score 15):

```
git update-ref refs/heads/new_branch refs/heads/master
```

In that bare repository if you have direct access to it. You may supply any reference (a tag for instance) or a commit in the last argument.

Below is a test script:

```
$ mkdir non-bare-orig

$ cd non-bare-orig/

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Temp/bare-branch/non-bare-orig/.git/

$ touch file1

$ git add --all && git commit -m"Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 9c33a5a] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1

$ touch file2

$ git add --all && git commit -m"Second commit"
[master 1f5673a] Second commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file2

$ git tag some_tag

$ touch file3

$ git add --all && git commit -m"Third commit"
[master 5bed6e7] Third commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file3

$ cd ../

$ git clone --bare non-bare-orig bare-clone
Cloning into bare repository 'bare-clone'...
done.

$ cd bare-clone/

$ git update-ref refs/heads/branch1 refs/heads/master

$ git update-ref refs/heads/branch2 some_tag

$ git update-ref refs/heads/branch3 9c33a5a

$ git branch -vv
  branch1 5bed6e7 Third commit
  branch2 1f5673a Second commit
  branch3 9c33a5a Initial commit
* master  5bed6e7 Third commit
```

Answer (score 5):

To create a new branch (locally) called branchname

```
git branch branchname
```

Then to sync it with the remote repository like GitHub (if applicable)

```
git push origin branchname
```

And to use it for development / make the branch the active branch

```
git checkout branchname
```

Comment: In a bare repository this results in an error:

*fatal: not a valid object name: 'master'.*